# SQL Server 2012 Edition Upgrade Error

Tags: sql-server-2012

I know I can't have a direct answer to this previously written somewhere, because this is somehow an special situation.

I installed a SQL Server 2012 Business Intelligence last month. I have found some issues, and happly noticed there's a service pack 1 already.

On the other hand, I was asked to perform an Edition Upgrade from SQL Server 2012 BI to the Enterprise version.

Well, I'm not sure if the provided Edition Upgrade option that comes with the SQL Server 2012 installation will work after I applied the path.

So, seems like I should run the upgrade to Enterprise first, then install the patch, but I'm getting an error while trying to do this:

> *SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:*
>
> *Attributes do not match. Present attributes (Directory, Compressed) ,
>   included attributes (0), excluded attributes (Compressed, Encrypted).*
>
> *Error code 0x84B40000.*

If I go to the link I get:

> *We're sorry
>
>   There is no additional information about this issue in
>   the Error and Event Log Messages or Knowledge Base databases at this
>   time. You can use the links in the Support area to determine whether
>   any additional information might be available elsewhere.*

Well, I would be glad to get the Edition Upgrade first, but I can't find a lot of information about this error.

Comment: If the [edition upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707783.aspx) does not work for you, it is really not that much work to install an Enterprise Edition instance, then backup/restore your databases and finally remove the old instance. The complication will be that you need to use a different instance name in that case. (And of course, you can always ring up Microsoft support to assist you with the SKU upgrade.)

Comment: I though of that route, but I need to keep the instance name since this database receives connections from 3 external systems. So, the solution is a total de-installation and then re-installation, including deploy like 20 dtsx, reprogramming jobs, etc, and the much longer downtime that I would want.

Comment: Then I suggest contacting Microsoft support. However in the length of time it takes for them to get you up and running, you might very well be able to finish all this work yourself, and they could end up with the same recommendation in the end anyway...

Comment: *Present attributes (Directory, Compressed) , included attributes (0), excluded attributes (Compressed, Encrypted).* this is a very convoluted way of telling you that you're trying to deploy in a Commpressed folder some files that require to be not compressed (eg. database files). Remove compression from the folder containing your current engine file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error sounded very cryptic, but it resulted to be a simple solution:

http://databasebestpractices.com/attributes-match-present-attributes-directory-compressed-included-attributes-0-excluded-attributes-compressed-encrypted/

It meant that the target folder was compressed, I didn't notice before, so I uncompressed "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" and the Edition Upgrade ended in 5 minutes succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded my previous edition  - SQL Server 2008 R2  to  Sql server 2012 Enterprise edition .
I was getting similar error while upgrading . I installed SQL server 2008R2 SP1 and then upgraded to SQL server 2012 Enterprise edition. It went just fine without errors.

You may want to refer to microsoft press guide.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/05/17/sqlauthority-news-sql-server-2012-upgrade-technical-guide-a-comprehensive-whitepaper-454-pages-9-mb/